# Distinguish an apk build with Cordova/Phonegap from a native one

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've been having some issues playing radio streams with `MediaPlayer` in a particular case. But that's not the point, the point is that I found an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.streema.simpleradio) that does exactly what I can't do, and I'm suspecting that is because It's using the Cordova / Phongap media plugin. My question is, given an apk there's anyway to know if the apk was build with Phonegap / Cordova or if was made with plain native Android code?

Comment: You could [decompile](https://apkstudio.codeplex.com/) it and look for any indications of cordova. Or just write a nice mail to the developers, maybe they'll tell you.

Comment: You can look at the licences (if any) inside the app settings or something. Maybe there are mentions to same by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You download the apk (there are online tools to do that)
2. You unzip the apk (an apk is just a zip with a specific content)
3. In the extracted folder search for the assets\www\ folder.
   If it's a cordova or phonegap app, you should see a file cordova.js in that folder.

(Yes, it's that easy to get all the sources of a cordova app :( )